# Equivalent of ON CONFLICT for UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a problem where I want to trim a column with preceding zeros.
The problem is there is a unique constraint on that table for few columns and the column which I am trying to fix is one of them.
Some data has been manipulated by the user which gave rise to these duplicate rows.
I dont want to touch them and leave them as it is.
But when I issue the following command, I am getting the unique constraint violation which does makes sense. But how to overcome it. I know for INSERT there is a ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING statement is there, but is there anything similar for UPDATE statement.
When I issue the following command, I am getting the following, since po_number 400102194 has been already inserted by the user from Front end.

```
update moa.part set po_number = TRIM(LEADING '0' from po_number) where po_number like '0%'
```

---

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "part_4col_uni_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (part_number, esn_id, po_number, tenant_id)=(642W9874-501, 1709, 400102194, 1) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

So I want to try the following something similar, but I know this will not work

```
update moa.part set po_number = TRIM(LEADING '0' from po_number) where po_number like '0%' 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT part_4col_uni_idx DO NOTHING;
```

How do I achieve the same effect

A sample record

```
part_id part_number part_description    esn_id  quantity    status_id   material_stream_id  source_id   oem po_number   manual_cso_commit   dr_status_id    airway_bill core_material   active  created_at  created_by  updated_at  updated_by  tenant_id   hpc_status_id   module_id   auto_cso_commit ship_out    receipt crit_ship   late_call   ex_esn  accum_offset    po_line_num
5344252 J644P21A    BOLT DOUBLE HEXAGON HEAD MACHINE    26  8-Jul   0   1   24  CFM INTERNATIONAL   100159499   NULL    NULL    NULL    TRUE    FALSE   2020-04-03 08:20:00.043306+00   NULL    2020-04-03 08:20:00.043306+00   NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    FALSE   FALSE   NULL    0   NULL
```

Comment: Does it make sense to you? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e6f26deede5cebc95994e0a12f7e61dd

Comment: yes..it makes sense...will try it and let you know...Thnx...part_id is the primary key though

Comment: ok, I just added an answer with a fiddle that uses part_id as pk.

Answer (score 0):

Join the `moa.part` table to itself to find all the part numbers that have a leading zero and also do not have a leading zero, and exclude those with a leading zero from the rows that are updated.  For example:

```
update moa.part
set po_number = trim(leading '0' from po_number)
where
    po_number like '0%'
    and po_number not in (
        select
            pa.po_number
        from
            moa.part as pa
            inner join moa.part as pb on trim(leading '0' from pa.po_number) = pb.po_number
                and pa.po_number <> pb.po_number
    ;
```

Though it seems as though it might be better to resolve those near-duplicate part numbers by merging or by renaming one of each pair.

Comment: I modified the query like below but its giving the result side by side..like all columns of moa.part and again all columns of moa.part by the side.      select  * from moa.part as pa
inner join moa.part as pb on trim(leading '0' from pa.po_number) = pb.po_number
and pa.po_number <> pb.po_number 
  and pa.active is true 
  and pa.part_number = pb.part_number
  and pa.part_description = pb.part_description
  and pa.esn_id = pb.esn_id
limit 10; Can I get it one column?

Comment: You used `select *`, which includes all columns from both aliases, `pa` and `pb`.  If you want only the part numbers from `pa`, use `select pa.po_number` instead.

Comment: Thnx a lot...got it

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an equivalent for updates, but you can use a subquery with a `EXISTS` to check if the conversion conflicts with another unique `po_number`, e.g.

```
UPDATE part q1
SET po_number = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM q1.po_number) 
WHERE 
  q1.po_number LIKE '0%' AND 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM part q2 
    WHERE 
      TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM q2.po_number) = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM q1.po_number) 
      AND q1.part_id <> q2.part_id);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e30ac6484fd2bbdebd44e8d33ebded2e)

Comment: I ran the query, but very few rows were updated 3414 from existing 31,076 and from the existing data when I run this individual query, that row is updated- update moa.part set po_number = TRIM(LEADING '0' from po_number) where po_number = '0100159769' and part_id = 5367699...so it missed updating a lot of rows it seems

Comment: Can you add to your question a sample of the records that haven't been updated bur should have?

Comment: @sromit would it be an option for you to create another column and add the new formatted po_numbers?

Comment: no..that is not a option..actually have to correct the po_numbers with preceding zeros so that they come as without preceding zeros in the UI

Comment: @sromit in that case I believe the only options would be to either remove the unique constraint and update the column or just trim the strings in query time. Kinda tricky situation ;)

Comment: I agree....I need to drop those indexes..make the change and re-enable the indexes again

Comment: @sromit if you drop the unique constraint and make the changes you won't be able to create the constraint again, as some number will no longer be unique ;)